# How to NHibernate Map Multiple Classes to the Same Table

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible to map 2 classes to the same table?

```
class Foo {}
class Bar : Foo {}
class Zap : Bar {}
```

Foo and Bar are Fluent Nhibernate auto mapped in one session factory.

All 3 classes are mapped with Fluent mappings in a different session factory:

```
class FooMap :  Class<Foo> {}

class BarMap :  Subclass<Bar> {}

class ZapMap :  Subclass<Zap> {
    public ZapMap() {
          Table("Bar");
    }
}
```

I want Zap to get mapped to the Bar table and not create a new one. Is this possible?

Comment: Do these help? http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/08/fluent-nhibernate-table-inheritance-discriminators/ http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/08/fluent-nhibernate-table-inheritance-discriminators-part-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change BarMap to:

```
class BarMap : Class<Bar> { }
```

and you have a "type" column on your Bar table (of type string for it to discriminate between Bar's and Zap's), then it should work

Take a look at http://fluentnhibernate.wikia.com/wiki/Fluent_mapping near the bottom of the page about Subclasses (you want  table-per-class-hierarchy)